# Does the copy constructor can not call another copy constructor?

Tags: c++

```
class Hello
{
private:
    int world;
public:

    Hello()
    {

    }
    Hello(const Hello& other)
    {
        world = other.world;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Hello a;

    Hello b = a;
    Hello c = Hello(a);  //not Hello c(a);

    return 0;
}
```

I guess it will call copy constructor just only 1 time at `Hello b = a;`.
And the `Hello c = Hello(a);` will call copy constructor 2 times.

(1) `Hello(a);` will call copy constructor and make a temporary Hello object.
(2) `Hello c = temporary object;` will call copy constructor for c object.

above is my guess of why the copy constructor will called twice at `Hello c = Hello(a);`

And i debugged it, but the result that shows Hello b = a; and  Hello c = Hello(a); 
is totally same in visual studio 2015. I didn't called like Hello c(a);

Is this the another type of explicit expression of call copy constructor?
Does the copy constructor can not call another copy constructor?

Comment: [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) `Is this the another type of explicit expression of call copy constructor?` what is "this"? What does "another type of expression" refer to?

Comment: `this` means Hello c = Hello(a);   and 'another type of expression' refer to Hello c(a); I thought before, "So it only call the copy constructor at once then, Hello c = Hello(a) is another expression of Hello c(a); ? ". I never heard about elision, It was the plausible assumption for me at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy [...] construction of a class [...]:
>
> - In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:
>
> T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x

The code:

```
Hello c = Hello(a);
```

Is initializing object `c` as a type `Hello` from a prvalue of type `Hello`. Copy elision is (and has to be) performed so copy constructor is not called (for the `=` - copy constructor is called for `Hello(a)`).

> Does the copy constructor can not call another copy constructor?

Well, sure it can.

```
Hello(const Hello& other) {
    Hello tmp = Hello(other);
    *this = tmp; // endless recursive function
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: in C++17 and later a prvalue isn't an object (yet), so there isn't a copy to be elided